# Stoke's Theorem problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I believe that this problem is solved using Stoke's theorem but I don't know how to parametrize the function

$$\iint ye^{(x^2+z^2)}$$

this is integrated over the surface S where S is the cylinder $x^2+z^2=9$

Help is very much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is it a double integration or triple integration?

Comment: hint - $e^9\iint y$

Comment: I thought about substituting it with the 9 but I didn't think it was right. Thanks WW1

Comment: Then would I integrate it in the order of dyd(theta)?

Answer (score 1):

First, parametrize your surface $S$:

$$
x=3sin(t), \quad y=y, \quad z=3cos(t),
$$

with $0\le t\le 2\pi$ and $y\in \mathbb{R}$.

Second, compute $\|r_t \times r_y \|= 3$.

You can now determine your integral:

$$
\iint_S y e^{x^2+z^2} dS = \int_0^{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}}ye^9\; 3 dy dt=3e^92\pi \int_{\mathbb{R}}y dy.
$$

The problem is, $\int_{\mathbb{R}}y dy$ does not converge. Are you sure you want to integrate on the infinite cylinder? Are you sure you are not asked to integrate on a portion of the cylinder (meaning $y$ would be bounded below and above)?

**Note.** This is not an integral that you can compute with Stoke's theorem. Stoke's Theorem is for integrals of **vector fields**, here we are integrating a **scalar function**.